# Convert C# string to JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

Does anybody know a way to convert a C# string to a JavaScript String in Asp.net.  My code looks like this:

```
<script>
  @{string thing = "Cats";}
  var thing = String(@thing);


  </script> 



</div>
<body onload="eventAlert(thing)"></body>
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a way to get a string value from server side (code behind) to client side (javascript).  Is that right?

Comment: The eventAlert(thing) function simply shows the string as an alert, but the code above does nothing unless i manually pass in the string.

Comment: and this string is held/generated in your c# codebehind?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to JavaScript Encode your string before you write it out, otherwise your string may contain characters that cause the JavaScript string constant to be terminated prematurely. You can do this with [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) in the System.Web namespace. Once you have done that you need to stop razor from HTML Encoding the result which can be done with [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) like this:

```
@{string thing = "Cats Special Chars \"!'£$%^&*()@;:";}
var thing = "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(thing))";
```

Comment: So this is pretty neat. Depending on your use case it might be more practical to just inject `"@myString"` however you can use `@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value: "hi", addDoubleQuotes: true)` and let the method output a string with or without double quotes added to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
var thing = "@(thing)";
```

Comment: This is how you would do it. Sometimes to make sure the razor engine doesn't get confused, it is also useful to use `var thing = "@(thing)";`.

Comment: Works very well until your string has a quote in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good ways to do this. But a very clean way is to use a cookie. This is clean because you are not injecting javascript code from the server into your static client code. Writing C# to create JavaScript and then insert that into a variable may have timing issues, depending on when your code runs and what .Net is doing.  Be very careful in reading strings back for security concerns.