# create a legal javascript file using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, string, escaping

Using c# I am trying to write a function that receives an XML file,
and outputs a JavaScript file with XML content assigned to a string variable

example

**XML input: a.xml**

```
<root>
 <book id="a">
   SAM 
 </book>
 <book id="b">
 </book>
   MAX
</root>
```

**JS Output: b.js**

```
var xml =   "<root><book id='a'>SAM</book><book id='b'></book>MAX</root>";
```

Im looking for a simple way to create a legal output as trying to manually escape all xml chars to create a legal js string will surely fail.

any ideas how this can be done painlessly ?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574931/573218

Comment: the proper way is write C# and JS separately, and invoke C# from JS (e.g. Web API) to get needed info.

Comment: @JohnKoerner the post describes how to get the string encoded using a web framework, i dont have those utils at my disposal, only c# (no  @{cats} notation)

Comment: @AlexSikilinda i guess proper is based on the usage, in my case i need the file to be present before sending to be interpreted in the js engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all text from your XML file using the following method in the System.IO namespace:

```
public static string ReadAllText(
    string path
)
```

Pass this to the following method in the System.Web namespace (requires .NET 4.6):

```
public static string JavaScriptStringEncode(
    string value,
    bool addDoubleQuotes
)
```

The combined code would look like this:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\a.xml");
string js = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(xml, false);
File.WriteAllText(@"..\..\b.js", string.Format("var xml=\"{0}\";", js));
```

Given the XML example you provided, the resulting JS looks like this:

```
var xml="\u003croot\u003e\r\n    \u003cbook id=\"a\"\u003e\r\n        SAM\r\n    \u003c/book\u003e\r\n    \u003cbook id=\"b\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/book\u003e\r\n    MAX\r\n\u003c/root\u003e";
```

And here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o1juvc0f/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm). It is serializer for JSON (subset of Javascript). Just try:

```
string xmlInJavascript = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("<root><item1>123</item1></root>");
```